# Store html data in a list using Javascript

Tags: javascript, list

I am creating a web app using javascript in which I have data like this:

```html
<h2>Data 1</h2>

<span>More: Data 1</span>
<span>Data 1</span>
<span>Data 1</span>
<span>Data 1</span>

<h2>Data 2</h2>

<span>More: Data 2</span>
<span>Data 2</span>
<span>Data 2</span>
<span>Data 2</span>

<h2>Data 3</h2>

<span>More: Data 3</span>
<span>Data 3</span>
<span>Data 3</span>
<span>Data 3</span>
```

Now, I want to store data like this

```
[
    {'title':'data1', 'More':'data1'},
    {'title':'data2', 'More':'data2'},
    {'title':'data3', 'More':'data3'}
]
```

I am not sure if it is possible. If it is, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried doing yourself so far? StackOverflow is to help you but not do the work for you.

Comment: It's also unclear what you want to do : should the data be extracted from the HTML, should the HTML be generated from the data, should updates to one be repercuted to the other?

Comment: You would need an HTML parser to read the data, maybe jquery, or you can use regex. Then, format the data into a JS object

Comment: @ferrix i did not tried anything as I don't even know how and what should be done

Comment: I think the most important question is : What do you mean by `Store` ... ? What do you want to do with thoses "datas" ?

Comment: I will export the data in excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it is what you want.

```js
let result = []
$("h2").each(function(index, element) {
  result.push({
    title: $(element).html().replace(' ', '').toLowerCase(),
    More: $(element).next("span").html().replace('More: ', '').replace(' ', '').toLowerCase(),
  })
})
console.log((result))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Data 1</h2>

<span>More: Data 1</span>
<span>Data 1</span>
<span>Data 1</span>
<span>Data 1</span>

<h2>Data 2</h2>

<span>More: Data 2</span>
<span>Data 2</span>
<span>Data 2</span>
<span>Data 2</span>

<h2>Data 3</h2>

<span>More: Data 3</span>
<span>Data 3</span>
<span>Data 3</span>
<span>Data 3</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use nested lists

```
<hX>title</hX>
<ul>
    <li>data1</li>
    <ul>More</ul>
    <li>data1</li>
</ul>


<hX>title</hX>
<ul>
    <li>data2</li>
    <ul>More</ul>
    <li>data2</li>
</ul>
```